# Javascript inheritance call and apply

Tags: javascript, call, apply, prototypal-inheritance

I have been trying to get this to work for some time now and keeps giving me undefined.

```js
function A(first, last){
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

A.prototype.concat = function(){
  return this.last + this.first;
}

function B(first, last){
  A.call(this, first, last);
  this.type = 'Long';
}

B.prototype.concat = function(){
  A.prototype.concat.apply(this, arguments);
}

var a = new B('A', 'B');
console.log(a.concat());
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing? If my concat method on A is accepting a parameter, then it works, but not without it.

Comment: `name.prototype.concat` should be `A.prototype.concat`?

Comment: If I fix that, the result is `BA`. Is that correct?

Comment: What's the point of `B`? You're never using it.

Comment: In your `concat` method -- instead of switching first and last name which makes no sense, just print it last name first then first name.

Comment: Barmar, Andrew - I just updated the snippet. Typos --- grrrrr...

Comment: It returns `undefined` as expected.

Comment: Did you mean `return A.prototype.concat.apply(this, arguments);`?

Comment: I think this should be closed as it falls into the category of a typo. *B.prototype.concat* has no return statement, so it returns *undefined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do

```
B.prototype.concat = function() {
  return A.prototype.concat.apply(this, arguments);
//^^^^^^
};
```

but of course the whole point of inheritance is that you don't need a wrapper function when you don't want to intercept anything, but would be able to call the *inherited* method directly:

```
B.prototype.concat = A.prototype.concat;
```

or better, to make the class inherit *all* methods from the `A` prototype dynamically:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```